# What's correct way to remove a boost::shared_ptr from a list?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, smart-pointers

I have a `std::list` of `boost::shared_ptr<T>` and I want to remove an item from it but I only have a pointer of type T* which matches one of the items in the list.

However I cant use `myList.remove( tPtr )` I'm guessing because shared_ptr does not implement `==` for its template argument type.

My immediate thought was to try `myList.remove( shared_ptr<T>(tPtr) )` which is syntactically correct but it will crash from a double delete since the temporary `shared_ptr` has a separate use_count.

```
std::list< boost::shared_ptr<T> > myList;

T* tThisPtr = new T(); // This is wrong; only done for example code.
                       // stand-in for actual code in T using 
                       // T's actual "this" pointer from within T
{
   boost::shared_ptr<T> toAdd( tThisPtr ); // typically would be new T()
   myList.push_back( toAdd );
}

{
   //T has pointer to myList so that upon a certain action, 
   // it will remove itself romt the list

   //myList.remove( tThisPtr);                      //doesn't compile
   myList.remove( boost::shared_ptr<T>(tThisPtr) ); // compiles, but causes
                                                    // double delete
}
```

The only options I see remaining are to use std::find with a custom compare, or to loop through the list brute force and find it myself, but it seems there should be a better way.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this just too non-standard a use to be doing a remove the clean/normal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enable_shared_from_this` can help with your problem, but it will require that the types you're using in the list derive from it:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html

If the type enables that functionality, you can get the shared pointer from the object itself by calling `shared_from_this()`.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, we can't directly compare the pointers. But there does exist `remove_if`, and we can specify our own predicate. The solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_contains_predicate
{
    ptr_contains_predicate(T* pPtr) :
    mPtr(pPtr)
    {}

    template <typename P>
    bool operator()(const p& pPtr) const
    {
        return pPtr.get() == mPtr;
    }

    T* mPtr;
};

template <typename T>
ptr_contains_predicate<T> ptr_contains(T* pPtr)
{
    return ptr_contains_predicate<T>(pPtr);
}
```

Just keep the above predicate in a header somewhere, and you can use it wherever you want.

```
myList.remove_if(ptr_contains(tThisPtr));
```

The best solution is to never lose hold of the `shared_ptr` in the first place, so we can just use `remove`, but the above is harmless anyway.

Comment: Damn you! (Beat me by one min...) +1

Comment: No need for a functor in C++0X:
myList.remove_if([ptr] (shared_ptr<Type> p) { return p.get() == ptr; });

Answer (score 4):

std::list's [remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/remove_if/) member is what you need:

Define a predicate

```
template <typename T> struct shared_equals_raw
{
  shared_equals_raw(T* raw)
    :_raw(raw)
    {}
  bool operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& ptr) const
    {
      return (ptr.get()==_raw);
    }
private:
  T*const _raw;
};
```

then you can call

```
myList.remove_if(shared_equals_raw(tThisPtr));
```

to have the list clean up nodes which have shared_ptrs to tThisPtr.

(Untested, so maybe some syntactic stuff needs fixing).

Michael Burr's advice re enable_shared_from_this is good though; it'd be better to avoid having the raw tThisPtr in play at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to step on your toes, I didn't see you already had the solution. +1 for the right answer, -0 for incorrect-ish syntax. :)

Comment: +1 for being correct but... GAH MY EYES! CAN'T DEAL WITH STRANGE INDENTATION PATTERN! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the shared pointer to remove it?

```
std::list< boost::shared_ptr<T> > myList;

boost::shared_ptr<T> tThisPtr = new T(); 

{
    myList.push_back(tThisPtr);
}

{
    myList.remove(tThisPtr);                     
}
```